# How can I combine two condition using IFS in google sheet to display particular data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to display `10` in a column if the `PaymentStatus` selected is `Un Paid` and `Day` selected is `Friday`. But If Day selected in Sunday, then display 5. I have tried below formula in Google sheet not working though, Can someone please advise on how can fix this one ?

`=IFS((D4="Un Paid"),(F4="Friday"),10) OR ((D4="Un Paid"),(F4="Sunday"), 5) )`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ifs(and(D4="Un Paid",F4="Friday"),10,and(D4="Un Paid",F4="Sunday"),5,1,)
```

Comment: Thank you, one question ...why do we need to use two AND's in the formula ?

Comment: because we're checking two conditions. If D4=Unpaid *AND* F4=Friday return 10, else if D4=Unpaid *AND* F4=Sunday return 5, else (1) return blank.

Comment: @soccerway, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Are you able to advise on this question >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247502/how-can-i-add-data-and-save-a-cell-data-in-google-sheet