# How can I add data and save a cell data in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I add up and save a cell data in Google sheet, if the PaymentStatus is `Un Paid` and Game Day is `Friday`, then $10 should be display in `R4` cell. Now for another date, if the PaymentStatus is `Un Paid` and Game Day is `Sunday`,then $5 should be added to previous value $10 and final $15 should display in `R4` cell, is that possible using Google sheet?
[image]

```
function storeValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // sheets are counted starting from 0
  var cell = sheet.getRange("Q4"); 
  var data = cell.getValue()
  var dataList = new Array();
   data += data;
   dataList = data;
  var cell1 = sheet.getRange("R4"); 
   cell1.setValue(dataList);
}
```

For the date 20-Feb-2022, if the PaymentStatus is `Un Paid` and `GameDay` selection is Friday, $10 should display in R4 cell of the `OutStanding Due Amt`colum. For a different date, if the user select PaymentStatus is `Un Paid` and `GameDay` selection is Sunday, the $5 should be added with previous amount $10 to display the `OutStanding Due Amt` due column in R4 cell, incase if Friday is again selected, the outstanding due amount will be $20.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `How can I add up and save a cell data in Google sheet, if the PaymentStatus is Un Paid and Game Day is Friday, then $10 should be display in R4 cell. Now for another date, if the PaymentStatus is Un Paid and Game Day is Sunday,then $5 should be added to previous value $10 and final $15 should display in R4 cell, is that possible using Google sheet?` and your script. Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Added the image,I will try to explain again

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the image. Unfortunately, from your additional image, I cannot understand the column number and the row number. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hope I have added a clear image with column name

Comment: Why you need appscript for this, i think you can do it using formulas too. using `Sumifs`!

Comment: Sorry someone advise me to do via appscript ...

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. I could confirm your sample image. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your sample image and your explanation. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill. By the way, your showing image is the sample input situation?

Comment: Hi, could you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, so that your situation can be reproduced easily and, hopefully, solved?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you use the formula `SUMIFS`. [Docs here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en). Learning this formula will make your life easier.

Comment: Sorry I tried using SUMIFS but couldn’t achieve the results yet. I want something diff. Not sure if I can achieve with it. When I select  Un Paid and certain day from column I should see value displayed in the desired cell, this is working. But now I perform selection a diff day, then I want to add previous displayed value to the new value in the same cell..is that possible using SUMIFS ? Where will save the old value to add up with new value?